# ActiveMQ; how to make a broker distribute messages among several transportConnectors

Tags: activemq-classic

is it possible to make the ActiveMQ broker distribute messages received on one transportConnector to other transportConnectors as well?
The concrete use case is this: I have a Java client sending messages using the openwire transportConnector and I would like to be able to read them on the mqtt transportConnector.
I use the sample jndi.properties file that is on the ActiveMQ page http://activemq.apache.org/jndi-support.html:

```
java.naming.factory.initial = org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory

# use the following property to configure the default connector
java.naming.provider.url = tcp://localhost:61616

# use the following property to specify the JNDI name the connection factory
# should appear as. 
#connectionFactoryNames = connectionFactory, queueConnectionFactory, topicConnectionFactry

# register some queues in JNDI using the form
# queue.[jndiName] = [physicalName]
queue.MyQueue = example.MyQueue

# register some topics in JNDI using the form
# topic.[jndiName] = [physicalName]
topic.MyTopic = example.MyTopic
```

I had to replace the default 'vm' transportConnector with the 'tcp' one because it did not execute using 'vm'.
The messages are pushed to my Java MessageListener instance but my mqtt client does not show them. I tried with different topics, started with 'example.MyTopic' up to '/example/MyTopic'.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Many thanks,

Roman

Answer (score 0):

The broker does that by default so you are not doing something right, check the admin console for producers and consumer registered on the given destinations to see what is going on.  You must remember that a Topic consumer will not receive messages sent to that Topic unless it was online at the time they were sent or you had previously created a durable topic subscription.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim!The admin console showed me the name of the topic the JMS client uses and now it works; I was very close with my guesses but just not exact...